# Angular: Problem accessing array of objects in *ngFor loop while string interpolation displays data in html but with error ctx is undefined in console

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular12

.HTML FILE

```html
<span class="total">Available Vaccines:</span>
   {{ vaccinationData?.sessions[0]?.center_id}} // This displays data on html with               //ctx.vaccinationData.sessions is undefined
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of vaccinationData.sessions" > <!-- This does not loop -->
        <mat-card class="card">
            <mat-card-header>
                <!-- <mat-card-title>{{ data?.center_id }}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle>{{ data?.address }}</mat-card-subtitle> -->
            </mat-card-header>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

.ts FILE

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesComponent } from '../../models/services/services.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'vaccine-available-slot-view',
  templateUrl: './available-slot-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./available-slot-view.component.scss'],
  /* changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, */
})
export class AvailableSlotViewComponent {

  
  constructor(private apiData: ServicesComponent){
    this.apiData.getVaccineData().subscribe(data=>{
      console.warn(data);
      this.vaccinationData=data;
      console.warn(this.vaccinationData?.sessions);
    })
  }
  vaccinationData: any =[];
}
```

Api data
https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=141&date=05-07-2021

Comment: what do both your `console.warn()` return?

Comment: Error on console while reading line 2 in .html file
ERROR TypeError: ctx.vaccinationData.sessions is undefined

Comment: console.warn was simply for checking if I was receiving data or not.
I should have removed them.

Comment: try initiating `vaccinationData: any ={};`

Comment: It works now thank you very much. I was stuck in it for two days.
So was I trying to save api data object into an array?

Comment: Yes exactly. Also, it's not a good practice defining your objects as `any` so to avoid this type of problems it's better to spend some more time strong typing your objects. Which is the biggest value of typescript. Like the answer below states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data structure you receive from the API match what you wrote in the HTML, remember that calling an API in asynchronous and takes a bit of time.

Until data from the API are available, your `vaccinationData` attribute is set as `[]` which:

- doesn't match what the HTML expects to work properly
- is not even of the correct type, this should probably be an `{}` (empty object) or `null`

You should:

- type correctly your data, using Typescript but defining variables as `any` defeat the whole purpose
- in the HTML, add a `*ngIf` to display the block only if the data are available (either using the data directly as a condition or an additional Boolean flag)

Comment: Thank you Sir. For the valuable feedback.